# Saving a docke image to a file with the Docker Client in go

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to create a tool that gathers dependencies and I want it to gather some docker images. I'm using the docker client go module which provides ImagePull and ImageSave methods where the image save method should return io.ReadCloser stream. I'm having trouble with invoking the method.

I'm trying to call it like so:

```golang
io, err := cli.ImageSave(ctx, ["docker.io/library/alpine"])
```

but I'm getting an error where the compiler is expecting:
`expected type, found ')'`

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here since the method should receive the context and a string array that represents the image on the host which I want to save...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you please share the entire function. how you are saving it as tar.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the mothod like this:

```golang
io, err := cli.ImageSave(ctx, []string{"docker.io/library/alpine"})
```

:)